How to find explicit formula from $C_{k,j}=C_{k-1,j}-C_{k,j-1}$?
For $k=1,2,\dots$, if I have boundaries $C_{k,1}=1$ and $C_{k,k+1}=0$, and recursion
$$C_{k,j}=C_{k-1,j}-C_{k,j-1}\text{ for } j=2,3,\dots,k,$$ how should I obtain an explicit formula for $C_{k,j}$?
I computed a few rows of the triangle of $C_{k,j}$ values:
$$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 &\ &\ &\ &\ \\
1 & -1 & 0 &\ &\ &\ \\ 
1 & -2 & 2 & 0 &\ &\ \\
1 & -3 & 5 & -5 & 0 &\ \\
1 & -4 & 9 & -14 & 14 & 0\\
1 & \cdots& \cdots& \cdots& \cdots& \cdots & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
Each internal value is the difference between its upper neighbor and its left neighbor.
This question arose from the polynomial coefficients of $\mathbb{E}\left(\left\vert \sum_{i=1}^{2k+1} X_i - \frac{2k+1}2 \right\vert\right)$ in this question, where $X_i\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p_i)$ independently.
I only have very limited exposure to 1-dimensional recursion but don't know how to work on such 2-dimensional recursions. Either a worked-out answer or references to relevant resources is appreciated.
For the 2nd column, it's $C_{k,2}=-(k-1)$. And given the previous column, I can find the next column through 1-dimensional linear recursion. The first a few columns I found so far are :
$$\begin{align}
C_{k,1}&=1 \\
C_{k,2}&=-k+1 \\
C_{k,3}&=\frac12 k^2-\frac12 k -1,\quad  k\geq2 \\
C_{k,4}&= -\frac{1}{6}k^3+\frac{7 }{6}k+1,\quad  k\geq3 \\
C_{k,5}&= \frac{1}{24}k^4+\frac{1}{12}k^3-\frac{13 }{24}k^2-\frac{19
   }{12}k-1, \quad k\geq 4 \\
\end{align}
$$
Although I can repeat this column by column by solving 1-dimensional recursions,  how should I get an explicit expression for an arbitrary column $j$?

Am I right to assume that you also know the value of $C_{k,1}$ to be $1$, a priori? otherwise I don't see how you would calculate this value using your recursion

@Immi Thanks. You are right. Just fixed my typo in the first line. It should be $C_{k,1}=1$.

@Immi Sorry I didn't get your point. What is $i$ in $-\sum_{n=j}^k C_{i,j}$ please?

To be more like Pascal's triangle,  you could change your indexing to (k+j) snd j.  Then instead of summing above you subtract in reverse.  (Convolution with (-1 ,1) not (1,1) as in Pascal's triangle.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle

@hoboonsuan Thank you so much. That's indeed helpful! I should study their proof carefully.
